# How do I select tags that contain mail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The mail address is specified in different places on the page. 
For example

```
<div>
  <p>a@a.ru</p>
</div>
<span>b@b.ru</span>
<a href="#"><b><span>c@c.ru</span></b></a>
```

I want to hang events on the tags where there is mail, and not their parent tags

However, the following code takes all tags at all, even body and events occur even when html is clicked

```
$('*:contains("@")').bind({
            mousedown: function () {
                console.log("Mousedown");
            },
            click: function(){
                console.log('Click');
            },
            copy : function(){
                console.log('Copy');
            },
            cut : function(){
                console.log('Cut');
            }
        });
```

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: You should also avoid the `*` selector when possible, and scope down as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` to remove elements that have children, so you'll only bind to the most deeply nested elements that match the selector.

```
$('*:contains("@")').filter(function() {
  return $(this).children().length == 0;
}).on({
  mousedown: function() {
    console.log("Mousedown");
  },
  click: function() {
    console.log('Click');
  },
  copy: function() {
    console.log('Copy');
  },
  cut: function() {
    console.log('Cut');
  }
});
```

However, this won't work for HTML like this:

```
<div>
  foo@bar.com
  <span>is the email</span>
</div>
```

What you really need to do is find all the text nodes that match the pattern, then select their immediate parents. But you can't select text nodes with selectors, they can only select tags. I'm not sure how to do this in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for participating! Can you tell me how to add an event to a found element? I'm a little confused about return

Comment: It's no different, you just call `.bind` or `.on` on the result. I've updated the answer to show it.

Comment: Thank you very match!! you are the best!